# Adding text on background Image and zooming the image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am newbie to HTML, CSS & Javascript. I want to add some background image. After the image is added, can I brake that image into small divs and add text into those divs? Is it possible. As well please give me some pointers on how to proceed.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe if you use a z-index manipulation. Did you try playing around with z-index? You'd need to make sure your body background is transparent, though.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Do you want multiple `<div>`s on the same background?

Comment: I would say it would just be easier to use a graphics editor to add text to the image. Adding this with CSS/HTML is possible, but seems heavy for doing what amounts to a very small graphic manipulation.

Comment: Do you have some code so we can see what direction you are currently heading with your program?

Comment: @thatidiotguy I agree with you. However, you lose the ability to dinamically change content if you use an image editor. Your suggestion  is similar to downloading an image to make it into a meme instead of using some form to slap the meme on top of that image.

Comment: @Shabab: I have the code, but it is not with the background image. Here is the deal, I am creating the small rectangular divs as per the dynamic content comes in. I am connecting those divs with jsPlumb lib. Now I want to zoom the divs such that whatever the center of the page is remains at center and is zoomed, while all other divs gets zoomed and moved away from each other. They should not overlap. I am able to zoom the divs, but not able realign them. Somewhere I read that zooming is easy with images and can be done easily so I was just wondering is adding text or creating divs is possible?

Comment: @Shabab Certainly true if the OP needs to dynamically add the text.

Comment: #thatidiotguy: I dont have any static text. I am parsing the xml file to get the data. So this wont work

Comment: @ Roddy of the Frozen Peas: Yes is that possible. If not then, can I add a text on the background image using html, css and jquery/ JS but not with some graphics editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this demo I made for you:

- http://jsfiddle.net/bq6Ju/1/

Every `chunk` is and absolute positioned `<div>` with `z-index:0` with [flower background](http://assets.freeprintable.com/images/item/thumb/lotus-flower.jpghttp://assets.freeprintable.com/images/item/thumb/lotus-flower.jpg). Background position is moved for every chunk.

On top you have `<div>` container, absolute positioned with `z-index:1` (this is why is on top) with some text.

Hope this will be some kick start for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me check if this is what I want.

Comment: :This is somewhat I need. One more thing, is there a way that the divs do not overlap each other. I am creating 100's of divs dynamically. using jquery/javascript. What I was thinking was to write CSS inside the JS but the problem is I am not sure about the calculation for specifying the location of the div.

Comment: instead of putting `background-position:0 0` to css use jQuery: `$(this).css('backgroundPosition', '0 -50px');` etc.

Comment: Sorry, can you please see why this jsfiddle is not working.
http://jsfiddle.net/unix_user/BvTCM/21/

Comment: you chosen "Mootols" innsead of jQuery. I have to sorry - i dont know why i missed the "zooming" part of your question. This trick with background won't work. Give me sth like 15 minutes i am going to make you another jsFiddle with zooming.

Comment: :Thanks a lot for all your help!

Comment: @unix_user you are welcome. Small update: http://jsfiddle.net/bq6Ju/5/ - notice second `.animate` is having 2x bigger values

Comment: the jsfiddle is not of MooTools it is of jquery. Here is the reference http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: You gave me link to Mootools jsFidle :)) Anyways there is small bug there. Using animate you have to center the inner div as well. It's easy to acomplish if you use `%` values instead of `px` values.

Comment: using % values inside the jquery while specifying new height and width right? 
Secondly, after the zoom is performed, I want the divs, not to be overlapped. I tried giving new top and left locations but then it aligns every div. I just want to separate the div which are going to be overlap? Is there a way to identify it?
Once again thanks

Comment: One small query regarding the above jsfiddle. When I do a zoom , the right side image goes to the next row or moves down 1 level if the preceding image is zooming down. What if, I do not want the image to go the next row but instead the width of my HTML page should get increase. I tried this, but could not get it done. Can you please let me know if its possible. Thanks